# Apache: Microsoft Azure and SSO Auth

Tags: apache, azure, authentication

Is it generally possible to have a Microsoft Azure in the background to act as a SSO Authentication server for Apache auth?

The example is:

1. There are many users inside the Microsoft Azure
2. I have a Webpage on a `Linux` server served by `Apache2`
3. The webpage should be protected (exactly like basic-auth) by Azure (via `SSO`)
4. If the user is signed in into Azure and has rights, he can see the website
5. If the user is not signed in, he will be redirected back to Azure's login-page and after successful login will back to the webpage.

Is this generally possible?

If so what technologies/modules do I have to use for apache in order to speak with Azure?

Thanks for any hints towards the right direction.

**Update**
The Azure server is already fully configured. I just need to sort out the end on Apache.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is Azure Active Directory. it is an Identity as a Service product that supports modern protocols like OAuth, OpenID Connect. There's a client SDK called ADAL (Active Directory Authentication Library), but since it's standard protocols, you can integrate with other standard based authentication libraries. For example, the [node.js](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-openidconnect-nodejs/) tutorial shows how to use [passport](https://passportjs.org/).
You didn't mention what web stack you are using but it's most likely listed here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-developers-guide/

On a side note: if you can host your app on [Azure Web App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/) then it has built in integration with Azure Active Directory, so you can add a layer of authentication on top of your website without modifying your application code.
More info on that here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, what I actually mean is how can I have apache talk to Azure. I don't want to integrate `auth` code into the web-application itself, but rather directly let Apache decide whether to show the page or not (depending on if the user is logged into Azure SSO or not).